# Sinatra Doesnt work on windows 7

Tags: ruby, windows, sinatra

I have a Widows 7 laptop and I'm trying to get Sinatra to work. I did exactly what the official site says yet it doesn't work. I have ruby 1.9.2, gem 1.8.1 and sinatra 1.2.6.

When I run this: `ruby hi.rb`

it says:

```
hi.rb:3:in `<main>': undefined method `get' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

I also tried: `ruby -rubygem hi.rb`

it says :

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- ubygem (LoadError)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
```

Comment: require 'sinatra'

get '/hi' do
  "Hello World!"
end

Answer (score 2):

Dunno if you made a typo, but the command is actually

ruby -rubygems hi.rb

Note the s on the option.

Answer (score 0):

Your file http://pastie.org/2135614 works on my system (Windows 7, Ruby 1.9.2p180, Sinatra 1.2.6).

But according to the error message (... no such file to load -- ubygem ...), I suppose your first test was :

```
require 'ubygem'
require 'sinatra'

get '/hi' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

The first line is wrong and causes the same error on line 29.

The first line should be « require 'rubygems' » or can be omitted (I don't remember exactly, but I think it is no longer necessary with Ruby 1.9).

Comment: no it wasnt michel... dont know whats the problem but doesnt work on my system